# "TypeError: undefined is not a function, Durandal SPA

Tags: javascript, jquery, durandal

I am trying to create simple Durandal SPA, however I am having the error below, and after hours, cant find what the issue is, my only though its maybe the data service define on the top of speakers.js, but not sure if my assumption is ok.

```
"TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at refresh (http://localhost:38945/App/speakers.js:21:16)
    at Object.activate (http://localhost:38945/App/speakers.js:17:20)
    at tryActivate (http://localhost:38945/Scripts/durandal/composition.js:112:44)
    at Object.composition.bindAndShow (http://localhost:38945/Scripts/durandal/composition.js:491:13)
    at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost:38945/Scripts/durandal/composition.js:602:29)
    at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost:38945/scripts/vendor?v=CoGrntPfi-B6C9wW1BBGgsUzERM99npj7WHKHsHaK8U1:1:37083)
    at l (http://localhost:38945/scripts/vendor?v=CoGrntPfi-B6C9wW1BBGgsUzERM99npj7WHKHsHaK8U1:1:35715)
    at Object.s.fireWith [as resolveWith] (http://localhost:38945/scripts/vendor?v=CoGrntPfi-B6C9wW1BBGgsUzERM99npj7WHKHsHaK8U1:1:36527)
    at Object.t.(anonymous function) [as resolve] (http://localhost:38945/scripts/vendor?v=CoGrntPfi-B6C9wW1BBGgsUzERM99npj7WHKHsHaK8U1:1:37507)
    at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost:38945/Scripts/durandal/viewEngine.js:167:25)"
```

**dataservice.js**

```
define(['logger'], ['durandal/system'],  function (logger, system) {

    var getSpeakerPartials = function (speakerObservable) {
        // reset the obersvable
        speakerObservable([]);

        //set ajax call
        var option = {
            url: '/api/speakers',
            type: 'GET',
            datatype: 'json'
        };

        //make call
        return $.ajax(options)
            .then(querySucceeded)
            .fail(queryFailed);

        function querySucceeded(data) {
            var speakers = [];
            data.sort(sortSpeakers);
            data.forEach(function (item){
                var s = new model.SpeakerPartial(item);
                speaker.push(s);
            });
            speakerObservable(speakers);
            log('Retrieved speakes from dremote data source', speakers, true);
        }

        function queryFailed(jqXHR, textStatus) {
            var msg = 'Error getting data. ' + textStatus;
            logger.log(msg,
                jqXHR,
                system.getModuleId(dataservice),
                true);
        }

        function sortSpeakers(s1, s2) {
            return (s1.firstName + s1.lastName > s2.firstName + s2.lastName) ? 1 : -1;
        }
    };

    var dataservice = {
        getSpeakerPartials: getSpeakerPartials
    };
    return dataservice;

    function log(msg, data, showToast) {
        logger.log(msg, data, system.getModuleId(dataservice), showToast);
    }
});
```

**speakers.js**

```
define(['dataservice'], function (ds) {
    debugger;
    var speakers = ko.observableArray();
    var initialized = false;
        var vm = {
            activate: activate,
            speakers: speakers,
            title: 'Speakers',
            refresh: refresh
        };

        return vm;

        function activate() {
            if (initialized) { return; }
            initialized = true;
            return refresh();
        }

        function refresh(){
            ds.getSpeakersPartials(speakers);
        }
    }
);
```

and my vs studio structure if that helps: http://screencast.com/t/uvqYqNrIz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try with

```
  define(['logger', 'durandal/system'],  function (logger, system) {
```

instead of

```
  define(['logger'], ['durandal/system'],  function (logger, system) {
```

Answer (score 0):

If you will see properly the function name is `getSpeakerPartials` and you are calling it as `ds.getSpeakersPartials()`. I think that is the problem.

If you see the error properly it says `undefined is not a function` on the line `21` in `speakers.js`. And you 21nd line is `ds.getSpeakersPartials()`.

Comment: yes I already fixed that, thanks for pointing out, but still got another error http://screencast.com/t/33vhyjcIoX

Comment: @L.V.SharepointArchitect you haven't added full screenshot, it doesn't show the line number & filename.

Comment: it was the define, see the answer from @anand4tech